# Why is my mount component wrapper not updating after action is dispatched while Enzyme and Jest testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have written React code to:

1. Authenticate user - enters username & password
2. A request is sent to an auth server and a token is received and
   stored in the Local Storage
3. On successfully storing the token, an action is dispatched to change
   the store state from isLoggedin: false to isLoggedIn:true
4. On changing the state to true, it redirects me to a new component.

I am testing for the above following scenario using the Moxios test.

I am not understanding why is my wrapper not updating with a new HTML code? My redux store state also changes, only if `response.status===200`.

Below is my test code:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { Login } from './Components/Form/Login';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { store } from './store/index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeMockStore } from '../MockUtil/utils';
import moxios from 'moxios';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import TestSearchRedirect from './Components/Form/TestSearchRedirect';
const $ = require('jquery');

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const setUp = (props = {}) => {
  const component = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Login />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
  return component;
};

const component = shallow(<TestSearchRedirect />);

it('render correctly text component', () => {
  const LoginComponent = renderer
    .create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
        <Login />
        <Route path="/search" component={TestSearchRedirect} />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
    .toJSON();
  expect(LoginComponent).toMatchSnapshot();
});

let wrapper: any;

describe('Login Page test', () => {
  let component;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = setUp();
  });

  // it('Shows spinner on Button click', () => {
  //   console.log(wrapper.html());
  //   wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  //   expect(wrapper.contains(<div className="spinner-grow" />)).toEqual(true);
  //   console.log(wrapper.html());
  // });

  it('check for existence of form', () => {
    const form = wrapper.find('form');
    expect(form.length).toBe(1);
  });
});

describe('Moxios', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
    wrapper = setUp();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });

  it('Calls the login class method on click', () => {
    const spyPreventDefault = jest.spyOn(Login.prototype, 'login');
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(spyPreventDefault).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('specify response for a specific request', function (done) {
    console.log(wrapper.html());
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    moxios.wait(function () {
      let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
      request
        .respondWith({
          status: 200,
          response: {
            token: '8972fjh45kbwbrhg4hj5g',
          },
        })
        .then(function () {
          let a = store.getState().login.isLoggedIn.isLoggedIn;
          expect(a).toEqual(true);
          expect(wrapper.html()).toEqual('<div className="Hrishi"><h1>Hrishikesh</h1> </div>');
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

This is my Login.tsx file

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Form.css';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { store } from '../../store';
import { LOGIN } from '../../constants/actionTypes';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spiiner from '../Spiiner';
import { showLoader } from '../../actions';
import { hideLoader } from '../../actions';
import axios from 'axios';
import TestSearchReddirect from './TestSearchRedirect'

interface IProps {
  login: any;
  dispatch: any;
}

interface IState {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

export class Login extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.storeCollector();
  }

  storeCollector() {
    let localStore = localStorage.getItem('login');
    if (localStore) {
      store.dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: { isLoggedIn: true } });
    }
  }

  handleUsernameChange = (event: any) => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handlePassword = (event: any) => {
    this.setState({
      password: event.target.value,
    });
  };

   login() {
   // this.props.dispatch(showLoader());
    axios
      .post('https://reqres.in/api/login', {
        email: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
      //    this.props.dispatch(hideLoader());
          if (response.status===200) {
            localStorage.setItem(
              'login',
              JSON.stringify({ token: response.data })
            );
            
            store.dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: { isLoggedIn: true } });
          } else {
            store.dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: { isLoggedIn: false } });
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
  //       this.props.dispatch(hideLoader());
        }
      );
   }

  render() {
    let loginPage = (
      <div className="form">
        <form className="form-signin">
          <div className="text-center mb-4">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <img
              className="mb-4"
              src="/docs/4.5/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg"
              alt=""
              width="72"
              height="72"
            ></img>
          </div>

          <div className="form-label-group">
            <input
              type="email"
              id="inputEmail"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Email address"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
            />{' '}
            <br></br>
          </div>

          <div className="form-label-group">
            <input
              type="password"
              id="inputPassword"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handlePassword}
            />
          </div>

          <button
            className="btn btn-lg btn-dark"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              this.login();
            }}
          >
            Sign in
          </button>
        </form>
        <a href="">
          <img
            id="img"
            src=""
            alt=""
          />
        </a>
        <Spiiner />
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {!this.props.login ? <div>{loginPage}</div> : <Redirect to="/search" />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

interface RootState {
  login: any;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
  console.log(state.login.isLoggedIn);
  return {
    login: state.login.isLoggedIn,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

Component to be rendered in Redirect

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class TestSearchRedirect extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Hrishi">
                <h1>Hrishikesh</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

All I want to know is, why this is not giving me the new HTML, rather shows me the HTML of Login page itself.

```
expect(wrapper.html()).toEqual('<div className="Hrishi"><h1>Hrishikesh</h1> </div>');
```

Comment: Try wrapper.update() before expecting updated dom node.
https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html

Comment: No that is not working. I tried

Comment: What exactly did you try? A reliable way to update the component is .setProps({}), as suggested in the link.

Comment: I tried wrapper.setProps({})
But it was of no help. Can you exactly point me in my code, as to where I can use it?

Comment: Right before `expect(wrapper.html())`. Also tests can cross-contaminate each other, you don't reset localStorage between them and don't reset store, I'm not sure it's the case for the code you posted but it's possible that `expect(a).toEqual(true)` gives false positive. I'd suggest to add `.toEqual(false)` for isLoggedIn at the beginning of `specify response for a specific request` to address this potential problem.

Comment: I did try it, it's not a False positive. 
Also, I tried setting wrapper.setProps({}) before expect(wrapper.html()). It still doesn't work. I get the login page only rendered and not the redirected component

Comment: Consider using `@`, otherwise users don't receive notifications. I wouldn't couldn't see a response if a tab weren't opened. Sorry, cannot suggest any other explanation without debugging it. That's the problem with blackbox tests. When a test fails, nothing suggests why and you can spend hours debugging it. I'd suggest to cover it with isolated unit tests first. The store can be tested apart from React and be mocked in component tests.